# FutureBuilder in flutter for chat application

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-application

I am creating a group chat app using firebase authentication. The flow of my application is such that i am letting the users to sign up and login. Once the user signs up or logs in in he/she is taken to the chat screen where they can send messages. The login flow works fine. But while creating a new user i am unable to retrieve the user data on the chat screen. Here's my code sample.

This is how i am switching between the screens.

```
Scaffold(
    body: StreamBuilder(
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData &&
              snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
            return ChatScreen();
          } else {
            return AuthScreen();
          }
        },
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges()));
```

This is the code for registering and signing in the user.

```
class _AuthScreenState extends State<AuthScreen> {
final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
var _isLoading = false;

void _submitAuthForm(
String email,
String password,
String username,
bool isLogin,
File f,
BuildContext ctx,
) async {
UserCredential authResult;

try {
  final collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
  var imageUrl = '';
  setState(() {
    _isLoading = true;
  });
  if (isLogin) {
    authResult = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email,
      password: password,
    );
  } else {
    authResult = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email,
      password: password,
    );
    final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref()
        .child('user_image')
        .child(authResult.user.uid);

    // await ref
    //     .putFile(f)
    //     .whenComplete(() async => imageUrl = await ref.getDownloadURL());

    await ref.putFile(f);
    final url = await ref.getDownloadURL();

    collection.doc(authResult.user.uid).set({
      'username': username,
      'email': email,
      'password': password,
      'imageFile': url
    });
  }
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (err) {
  String errorMessage = '';
  if (err.code == 'weak-password') {
    errorMessage = 'The password provided is too weak.';
  } else if (err.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
    errorMessage = 'The account already exists for that email.';
  } else if (err.code == 'user-not-found') {
    errorMessage = 'No user found for that email.';
  } else if (err.code == 'wrong-password') {
    errorMessage = 'Wrong password provided for that user.';
  } 
  
  Scaffold.of(ctx).showSnackBar(
    SnackBar(
      content: Text(errorMessage),
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(ctx).errorColor,
    ),
  );
  setState(() {
    _isLoading=false;
  });
} on PlatformException catch (err) {
  var message = 'An error occurred, pelase check your credentials!';

  if (err.message != null) {
    message = err.message;
  }

  Scaffold.of(ctx).showSnackBar(
    SnackBar(
      content: Text(message),
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(ctx).errorColor,
    ),
  );
  setState(() {
    _isLoading = false;
  });
} catch (err) {
  setState(() {
    _isLoading = false;
  });
  if (_isLoading == false) {
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).errorColor,
      content: Text(err.toString()),
    ));
  }
}
```

}

This method is responsible for retrieving user data from the users collection.

```
Future<User> getUserByUid(String uid) async {
  final doc = await collection.doc(uid).get();
   return User.fromJSON(doc.data());
}
```

This one is responsible for displaying the data on the chat screen.

```
class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_ChatScreenState createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}

class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
var future;
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
future= FirebaseService()
        .getUserByUid(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid);

}
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return FutureBuilder(
    future: _user,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
       if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
          snapshot.hasData) {
        
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              toolbarHeight: 70,
              leading: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
                  child: InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.of(context)
                          .pushNamed(SettingsScreen.routeName);
                    },
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundImage: snapshot.data.imageUrl != null
                          ? NetworkImage(snapshot.data.imageUrl)
                          : null,
                    ),
                  )),
              title: Text(
                snapshot.data.username,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              ),
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              actions: [
                IconButton(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    icon: RadiantGradientMask(
                        child: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.userFriends)),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => ListOfFriends()));
                    }),
                IconButton(
                  //color: Colors.deepPurple,
                  tooltip: 'Logout',
                  icon: RadiantGradientMask(
                      child: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.signOutAlt)),
                  onPressed: () {
                    FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
                  },
                )
              ],
              elevation: 0.5,
              centerTitle: true,
            ),
            body: Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(child: Messages()),
                NewMessage(),
              ],
            ));
      } else {
        
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }
    });
```

}
}

This code never comes out of the if block and the circular progress indicator goes on forever. Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First avoid to name your future as future.

To answer you:

```dart
final Future<String> _user; // add prefix 'late' if you are already using sound null safety.

Future<String> _getUserByUID(final var uid) async {
    return await FirebaseService().getUserByUid(uid);
}

@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _user = _getUserByUID(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid);
}

[...]

return FutureBuilder(
    future: _user,

[...]

if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done && snapshot.hasData) {
      print('the data is ${snapshot.data}');
      return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
       [...]
));} else
     return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
}
```

Now it should be working, let me know if it solves it!

edit: you have to add `snapshot.hasData` condition or your code may get null;

Comment: It didn't work. The getter imageUrl was called on null is what the error i am getting. This means the snapshot.data is null

Comment: it may be because you have to wait for snapshot.hasData to be true, it may be preferable to build your FutureBuilder with if ```(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done && snapshot.hasData)``` first and then return CircularProgressIndicator if both conditions are not true, I edited my answer

Comment: i tried every possible if checks, but still it first goes into the if condition where connection state is waiting and then directly goes to else condition. Could it be because of the way i am registering and immediately retrieving ?

Comment: ```if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done && snapshot.hasData) { ... } else
     return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());``` should work. Please update your question with this code if it is still not working? once the connectionState is done it does not mean that snapshot.hasData is yet true, so you need to add this condition.

Comment: i edited the code could you please have a look? I am still stuck !! Sorry for the hassle and thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the top of my answer: You have to change your future variable at the top to: 
```final Future<String> _user; 

Future<String> _getUserByUID(final var uid) async {
    return await FirebaseService().getUserByUid(uid);
}

@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _user = _getUserByUID(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid);
}```

Comment: I already changed that. Forgot to edit in the question. 

Comment: its very important that you create a separate async fonction (getUserByUID) as you need to **await** the result from Firebase

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228637/discussion-between-arbaz-adam-and-antonin-gavrel).